# Unable to vibrate Android 5.0+ devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-vibration

I have been using the below code to vibrate the device when displaying a notification:

```
long[] vibratePattern = {0, 500};
NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity()).setVibrate(vibratePattern)
```

I now notice that for devices running Android 5.0+ , it shows up a notification box at the top but does not vibrate the device.

Is there a different way to accomplish this on newer Android flavors?

Comment: Have you tried it with the screen off?

Comment: It is a Polling Notification and not a Push. Hence, the app has to be in the foreground.

Comment: Then why are you using a notification? Wouldn't you just use the [Vibrator class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)?

Comment: Aaah...thanks. I will look into that class.

Comment: Does your app hold the `VIBRATE` permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only wanting to vibrate the device and not actually using a notification while your app is the in the background, you should use the [Vibrator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) class.

On Android 5.0+ devices, a 'Heads Up Notification' is used if the screen is on and the notification includes vibration/sound. This prevents the device from vibrating when the screen is on and the user is looking at it, hence why the notification does not vibrate the device.